# Convert monetary properties of an object

Tags: c#

My project has the following structures:

```
public struct Money
{
    public CurrencyCodes Currency;
    public decimal Amount;
}

public class Foo
{
    public Money AdultFare { get; set; }
    public Money ChildFare { get; set; }
    public Money BabyFare { get; set; }
    public Money AdultFee { get; set; }
    public Money ChildFee { get; set; }
    public Money BabyFee { get; set; }
    public Money TotalFare { get; set; }
    public Money TotalFee { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to convert all Foo monetary fields from one currency to another.
What is the best solution design? use reflection? some another idea?

Comment: Why didn't you use an `array` or `collection` in the first place?

Comment: Not make sense in the design!

Comment: Please explain more details of your scenario. I have never seen this kind of variable list that cannot be solved by collection or array.

Comment: ok, I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't think you want to go the route of reflection.  Perhaps you just need a hard coded method to go through all of the properties.  To simplify, you could create `FareAndFee` class that has `Money Fare` and `Money Fee`.

Comment: Just a FYI `Money` is a [mutable struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). You can get yourself in to a lot of trouble that way, are you sure you don't want it to be a class?

Comment: This was a doubt from the beginning, in fact, the first version was a class that was subsequently refactored into a struct. I will rethink this! TKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making all of those `V` fields into an array, like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Money[] V { get; set; } // instantiate as "new Money[10]"
}
```

You could then go through your `V` array and easily convert each one, like so:

```
// in class Foo
public void ConvertAllMoney(CurrencyCodes newCurrency)
{
    foreach (Money m in V)
        m = m.ConvertTo(newCurrency);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to make an array, you could in fact use reflection, as you suggested:

```
// in class Foo
public void ConvertAllMoney(CurrencyCodes newCurrency)
{
    foreach (var p in typeof(Foo).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Money)))
    {
        Money m = (Money)p.GetValue(this, null);
        p.SetValue(this, m.ConvertTo(newCurrency), null);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You will want to use my second suggestion, Reflection, as your variables are not in the form of a list.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `V1`, `V2`...`V10` create a list:

```
List<Money> V = new List<Money>();
V.Add (new Money()); //repeat 10 times
```

Then you can iterate:

```
foreach (Money m in V)
{
  //Do your conversion
}
```

**Suggestion After Edit**

```
List<Money> AllMoneyFields = new List<Money>();
public Foo()
{
  AllMoneyFields = new List<Money>
    {AdultFare,ChildFare,BabyFare,AdultFee,ChildFee,BabyFee,TotalFare,TotalFee};
}
```

Then in another "Convert" method you can iterate through `AllMoneyFields`.

**Suggestion 3**

If you want to protect for future `Money` properties use an `enum` to describe the property:

```
//Add a field to Money: public MoneyDescription Description;
enum MoneyDescription
{
  AdultFare,
  AdultFee,
  ....
  TotalFee
} 

List<Money> V = new List<Money>();
foreach (MoneyDescription md in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MoneyDescription)))
{
  V.Add(new Money() {Description = md});
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, does not make much sense to use the fields as an array.

Comment: @EltonGarcia Couple more ideas for you.